# im trying to use pydub with discord.py, but no audio is coming out

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pydub

I'm trying to use pydub with discord.py, as pydub has features that i wanna add to my discord bot. However, i can't hear any audio coming out from the bot, and there are no error messages. What do i do? here is my code:

```
@bot.command(name='playtest', case_insensitive=True) 
async def voice(context):

    channel = context.author.voice.channel

    await channel.connect()

    guild = context.guild
    voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=guild)
    loop = AudioSegment.from_file(str('C:\\Users\\ryanc\\Music\\lofibot project\\nuver\\nuver_piano.wav'))
    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(str(loop), executable='ffmpeg'), after=None)
    await context.channel.send("should be playing i think")
```

Comment: Make sure that PyNaCl is installed: `pip install pynacl`. I had the same problem and this fixed it.

Comment: i already have pynacl. once u had it were u able to play pydub in discord? or just pydub in general?

Comment: That is what worked for me, although I’m not very familiar with pydub, so I was just suggesting what worked for me. Sorry I can’t help any further.

Comment: can u please show me ur line of code?

Comment: `audio_obj = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)`
`voice_client.play(audio_obj, after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx, video))`


Same as yours, except I'm using a link for the source instead of a location on my computer. I noticed that you didn't have any FFMPEG_OPTIONS inputted to the `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio` object so that might be a problem.
I think the problem might be that you're casting the `AudioSegment.from_file` to a string, but like I said, I'm not using pydub so that might not be the case.